# Convergence of asset prices and income they generate

Tags: investing, stock-valuation

Listened to a video from Bridgewater where the CO-cio states that there were two ways for prices and income it generates to converge. Either via falling prices which is straightforward or via "inflation" which I don't understand..anyone understands this? How does inflation lead to justified prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are paying $4 for a quart of milk while everyone around you is paying $2. It would seem natural that since you are paying too much, the price should drop and get close to the going rate.

Or, inflation. Each year, we all pay a bit more, and ultimately, we are paying closer to that $4 price.

(I am not agreeing or disagreeing with the author's premise. Just kindly explaining what I believe his theory to be.)

In the case of the overvalued stock, if the earnings rise with inflation, the dividends can rise as well, and eventually, the P/E and dividend are sensible.

Comment: right, we have inflation and the stock price remain the same? i.e it falls in price in some sense. But dosnt the dividend need to keep up with inflation in that case? or is it sufficent that it remains the same?

Comment: edited to respond to the comment

Comment: thanks, I see why you dont agree with him. If earnings keep increase so will prices..I think..

Comment: The disclaimer was to let me address the potential math, but avoid debate.